# NSMutableArray global

Tags: ios, objective-c, codenameone

I am trying to use the equivalent of an `ArrayList` in Objective-C. I understood that I have to use a `NSMutableArray`. I want to have a list of strings (`NSString`). The point is that my list should be accessible from any method in my class. The aim is to have a instance variable as in java. My problem is that when I try to add object in the list my app crashes (I don't have an error to show since I use codename one).

My testNativeImpl.h contains :

```
@interface testNativeImpl : NSObject {
     NSMutableArray* mNewStreamsId;
}
```

And in my testNativeImpl.m :

```
-(id)init{
     self = [super init];
     mNewStreamsId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     return self;
 }
```

I try in different methods to add a string like this :

```
NSString* sId = stream.streamId;
[mNewStreamsId addObject:sId];
```

`sId` is a valid string since when I print it it is okay.

But the `addObject` crashes the app.

How should I do? 
A singleton?

Comment: We need the details of the crash to diagnose what's going on. If you can't capture the details of the crash because of "codename one", then create [the simplest, stand-alone, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. And then we can diagnose that. But it's hard to imagine how the above would crash, which is why we need to see details.

Comment: this should work. show the code where you create the instance of your class.

Comment: By the way, I assume you are using automatic reference counting? (It's been the default memory management for years, but non-ARC code of yore can sometimes cause problems of dangling pointers.) Also, in addition to showing the creation of `testNativeImpl` instance, as john elemans suggested, can you also show us the context in which your `addObject` code was called? But in answer to your question, no, singleton is not the right solution.

Comment: You are using Objective-C in a badly non-standard way. That mutable array should be a property, with a new newStreamIds (proper English). init should return "instancetype", not "id", and it should check whether [super init] returns nil.

Comment: Use the static analyzer (Xcode: Command-Shift-B) and see what it says.

Comment: @gnasher729 ... just to add to your observations, for compatibility with ARC, [per the Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), he shouldn’t start the property name with `new`, either (or, if he feel you must, you have to specify a different getter name). Personally, I’d call it `streamIds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that can go wrong, one of the harder parts is that we can't use ARC as it collides with the GC. So make sure you retain the object:

```
-(id)init{
     self = [super init];
     mNewStreamsId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [mNewStreamsId retain];
     return self;
}
```

You would need to free it in `dealloc` but from the sound of it you are keeping it for the duration of the app so it should work fine without releasing as long as you keep a reference to the native interface from the Java side.

I would also suggest logging to make sure the init code is invoked correctly and the mutable array was allocated. If you have access to xcode then running this within xcode might prove useful as the crash within the IDE provides additional details.

Comment: I also had a problem with an OpenTok method but this helped, Thank you. I had to add and change a method implementation in the native implementation in the ios part.

Comment: This answer is not correct. It it going to leak. In manual reference counting code, the `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` creates an object with a `+1` retain count. The `retain` is going to increase the retain count to `+2`. If you `release` it in `dealloc`, that's going to drop the retain count to `+1` (not `0`), thereby leaking. If he instantiated the array with `[NSMutableArray array]` (which returns an autorelease object), then, yes, you'd need to `retain`. But not with `alloc`/`init`. Frankly, in this day and age, he should be using ARC, to eliminate all of this silliness.

Comment: By the way, iOS does not use garbage collection (which is what I assume you mean by GC). macOS used to offer that in days of yore, but iOS never has. It's always been reference counting.

Comment: I can't speak to that, but the Objective-C code must follow manual reference counting rules, no? If so, above code will over-retain the object in question. I can't believe that Codename One requires you to write Objective-C code that not only must use manual reference counting, but also code that violates all of the standard manual reference counting rules.

Comment: As I mentioned before since this is a singleton over retention doesn't matter for this specific case